# Дизайн модели объектов

Tags: ооп, uml

Не могу справиться с дизайном модели объектов. Требуется лишь нарисовать UML диаграмму, а не само программирование. Если нет возможности помочь реально советом, может кто посоветует дельную книгу или статью, книг много все объемные а мне надо сдать задачу через неделю... потому надеюсь на более конкретную помощь здесь.

> Дано:
>
> Разные метеостанции в разных городах измеряют разные факторы:
>   температура (°C), влажность воздуха (%), количество осадков (мм/кв.м),
>   скорость ветра (м/сек), направление ветра (в, з, ю, с). Измерения
>   выполняются в равном интервале времени (каждые 60 мин).
>   Предполагается, что измерения наличны в файле, который находится в
>   директории, которая должна быть настроена во внешнем конфиг файле.
>
> Все данные агрегируются и могут быть выведены в простые отчеты:
>
> - вывод всех значений по метеостанции
> - вывод всех значений конкретного фактора (например температура) по метеостанции
> - вывод минимальной/максимального значения определенного фактора и станции (например максимальная температура в Москве)
>
> Составить модель программы - дизайн приложения:
>
> - модель объектов
> - слой данных
> - сервисы
> - вспомогательные классы и методы
>
> Формат данных входящего файла: дата, время, город, тим измерения, тип
>   единицы изм, значение

Comment: только дизайн модели объектов?

Comment: знаешь что такое DAO ?

Comment: Знаю что такое DAO. Изначально решил задачу через один объект Measurment и DAO. Но вернули мне мое решение...как не обдуманое. Сказали Measurment  разделить на много объектое использовать enum по типу измерений. Т.е както сконструровать приложение с максимальной гибкостью. Вот тут уже и мозгов не хватило

Comment: а можешь прислать свой прежний код, чтобы не допускали тут такую же ошибку ?

Comment: https://github.com/Dermenji/Weather/tree/master/src/com/sirma/weather
У меня там есть и какая то реализация конкретных методов. Но она меня в случае не интересует. Только сам скелет и структура классов/методов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нарисовал как должно быть. так норм? Далее используй свои классы,чтобы заполнить все. 
Вот тебе и масштабируемость, и абстракция, и дао, и сервисы, Формат данных входящего файла

```
package oop.items;

/**
 * Created by sahakyan on 6/24/2016.
 */
public class City {
    private String name;
    private Factors factors;

    public City(String name, Factors factors) {
        this.name = name;
        this.factors = factors;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Factors getFactors() {
        return factors;
    }

    public void setFactors(Factors factors) {
        this.factors = factors;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "City{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", factors=" + factors.toString() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

2

```
package oop.items;

import java.util.*;

/**
 * Created by sahakyan on 6/24/2016.
 */
public class Factors {
    private int temperature;
    /**
     * влажность воздуха
     */
    private int airHumidity;
    /**
     * количество осадков
     */
    private Rainfall rainfall;

    /**
     * скорость ветра
     */
    private WindSpeed windSpeed;

    /**
     * направление ветра
     */
    private WindDirection windDirection;

    /**
     * интервал времени
     */
    private Calendar interval;

    public Factors(int temperature, int airHumidity, Rainfall rainfall, WindSpeed windSpeed, WindDirection windDirection, Calendar interval) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
        this.airHumidity = airHumidity;
        this.rainfall = rainfall;
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
        this.windDirection = windDirection;
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public int getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemperature(int temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public int getAirHumidity() {
        return airHumidity;
    }

    public void setAirHumidity(int airHumidity) {
        this.airHumidity = airHumidity;
    }

    public Rainfall getRainfall() {
        return rainfall;
    }

    public void setRainfall(Rainfall rainfall) {
        this.rainfall = rainfall;
    }

    public WindSpeed getWindSpeed() {
        return windSpeed;
    }

    public void setWindSpeed(WindSpeed windSpeed) {
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
    }

    public WindDirection getWindDirection() {
        return windDirection;
    }

    public void setWindDirection(WindDirection windDirection) {
        this.windDirection = windDirection;
    }

    public Calendar getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    public void setInterval(Calendar interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Factors{" +
                "temperature=" + temperature +
                ", airHumidity=" + airHumidity +
                ", rainfall=" + rainfall.toString() +
                ", windSpeed=" + windSpeed.toString() +
                ", windDirection=" + windDirection +
                ", interval=" + interval.toString() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

3

```
package oop.items;

/**
 * Created by sahakyan on 6/24/2016.
 */
public class Rainfall {
    private int value;
    private String type;

    public Rainfall(int value, String type) {
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Rainfall{" +
                "value=" + value +
                ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

4

```
package oop.items;

/**
 * Created by sahakyan on 6/24/2016.
 */
public enum WindDirection {
    EAST,
    WEST,
    SOUTH,
    NORTH
}
```

5

```
package oop.items;

/**
 * Created by sahakyan on 6/24/2016.
 */
public class WindSpeed {
    private int value;
    private String type;

    public WindSpeed(int value, String type) {
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "WindSpeed{" +
                "value=" + value +
                ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

6

```
package oop.services;

import oop.dao.*;
import oop.items.*;

import java.util.*;

/**
 * Created by sahakyan on 6/24/2016.
 */
public class FactorsService extends AbstractController {
    private ArrayList<City> cityArrayList = new ArrayList<City>();

    public FactorsService() {

    }

    public List getAll() {
        return cityArrayList;
    }

    public Object update(Object entity) {
        return null;
    }

    public Object add(Object entity) {
        return null;
    }

    public Object getEntityById(Object id) {
        return null;
    }

    public Object getByName(Object name) {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean remove(Object id) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean create(Object entity) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

7

```
package oop.dao;

import java.util.*;

/**
 * Created by sahakyan on 6/24/2016.
 */
public abstract class AbstractController<E, K>  {
    public abstract List<E> getAll();
    public abstract E update(E entity);
    public abstract E add(E entity);
    public abstract E getEntityById(K id);
    public abstract E getByName(K name);

    public abstract boolean remove(K id);
    public abstract boolean create(E entity);
}
```

Comment: Круто, большое спасибо!!!

Comment: Пожалуйста, посоветуйте книгу дельную, как научиться так мыслить и уметь создавать такие структуры.

Comment: можно Стив Макконнелл. Совершенный код. 2007 (In English - Code Complete)
 Design Patterns подтянуть